# Filter settings in OpenContent (dotnetnuke) doesn't work

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I installed the last version of OpenContent Module, and I add some items using catalog template, but when I try to filter the content using Filter Settings, it doesn't work. Seems that for some reason the module doesn't find the results.

Someone knows how it works or what I doing wrong?
[Filter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZixUr.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for some reason only accepts lowercase values and no symbols like: &, #,... try to change the "Membership" for "membership".